# Retrieving variables from flash video with perl

Tags: flash, perl, information-extraction

I am downloading a flash video with Perl. Is there a way to interact with the flash video like retrieving variables from the flash video, like you can do in C#?

For instance, in C# you can put a `Shockwave Flash Object` on a form and then you can do `GetVariable`/`SetVariable` on that object. I don't want to/don't care if I can *see* the video, I just want something like the `Get`/`SetVariable` of the C# Shockwave Flash object.

Comment: Give the name of the C# library or a code example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what kind of variables you're looking for, but `CGI::Application::Plugin::Flash` can be used to set *and* get variables from a flash object: http://search.cpan.org/~bcbailey/CGI-Application-Plugin-Flash-0.02/lib/CGI/Application/Plugin/Flash.pm

Comment: Do you know if this works on Actionscript 3 swfs? (C#'s ShockwaveFlashObject does not)

Comment: Well, the last version of this module was release in March 2008, and (according to wikipedia) ActionScript 3 came out in 2006, so my best guess is that it should work, but I haven't tried it with different known versions of AS.